# Turning lists into columns in csv with python and pands

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to remove data from a csv and then put the unremoved data back into the csv. I'm converting each column into a list then removing the unwanted string from each column, but I'm struggling to put the csv back together because each list gets put back in by row not column. So instead of:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Todd | Amy |
| Ashley | Ashley |
| Greg |  |

I get:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Todd | Ashley | Greg |
| Amy | Ashley |  |

Any ideas how to do this through python and pandas

I honestly have no idea how to fix this cause my knowledge of python and pandas is very limited and I can't find much on the internet

Comment: You just need to transpose this dataframe.  `df.T`

Comment: What is the logic to "remove unwanted strings"? Without a clear and complete example, it's impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score -2):

To put the columns back together as they were originally, you can use the `pd.DataFrame()` function from the Pandas library to create a new DataFrame from the updated lists. Here's an example code snippet that you can modify to fit your specific needs:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the original csv file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('original_file.csv')

# convert each column into a list, remove unwanted data, and store in a new list
column_a_list = [item.replace('unwanted_string', '') for item in df['Column A'].tolist()]
column_b_list = [item.replace('unwanted_string', '') for item in df['Column B'].tolist()]

# create a new DataFrame with the updated lists
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': column_a_list, 'Column B': column_b_list})

# write the new DataFrame to a csv file
new_df.to_csv('updated_file.csv', index=False)
```

In this example, we read the original csv file into a DataFrame using `pd.read_csv()`, then convert each column into a list and remove any unwanted data using a list comprehension. We then create a new DataFrame using the updated lists and write it to a new csv file using `to_csv()`. Note that we use `index=False` to prevent the row index from being written to the csv file.

Comment: This is really helpful! Do you think there is any way to make this into a loop? When I run this I'll have an unspecificed amount of columns in the dataset every time, and a lot of columns.

Comment: You can do something like this

```python

import pandas as pd

# read the original csv file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('original_file.csv')

# iterate over each column in the DataFrame
for col in df.columns:
    # convert each column into a list, remove unwanted data, and store in a new list
    updated_col_list = [item.replace('unwanted_string', '') for item in df[col].tolist()]
    # create a new column with the updated list
    df[col] = updated_col_list

df.to_csv('updated_file.csv', index=False)

```
if it's useful, don't forget to vote!